# Android appium Permission Denial: starting Intent

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

Anyone can help me to see this permission issue is due to the app which I need developer to re-build with permission open?
or it is my adb command issue?
or the intent argument is used wrongly?

At android phone,

1st screen:
com.ninetest.hd3.test.testDetectActivity

2nd screen:

com.ninetest.hd3.activity.MailActivity

**When executing adb command with 1st screen, error occurred. if I changed the appActivity to 2nd screen then no issue. but i cannot skip first screen if I need to run appium test cases.**

I cannot skip the intent argument as well, otherwise the app which installed under work profile is not launced.

```
**error**

C:\Users\tester>adb shell am start --user 10 -n "com.ninetest.hd3.work.cac/com.ninetest.hd3.test.testDetectActivity"
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.ninetest.hd3.work.cac/com.ninetest.hd3.test.testDetectActivity }
Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ninetest.hd3.work.cac/com.ninetest.hd3.test.testDetectActivity } from null (pid=9047, uid=2000) not exported from uid 1010396

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ninetest.hd3.work.cac/com.ninetest.hd3.test.testDetectActivity } from null (pid=9047, uid=2000) not exported from uid 1010396
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1386)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:921)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:694)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1932)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:625)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1707)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1603)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4218)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:518)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:172)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:12243)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:916)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:790)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5310)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3383)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1056)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1029)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think You need to set `android:exported="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your Activity

Comment: yup I guess so. But I don't have the apk, how would I modify it? I think only developer can do so right.?

Comment: if you don’t have the source of the project yes, only the developer can change it, you need the source code to change it,
don't you have?

Comment: I don't have source code. I'm not sure if it is set with purpose or not. Might be security reason it cannot allow exported true. Any other idea workaround? To ignore this screen activity, since I do not need to intersect on this screen. I will tap something on this screen manually to proceed next screen then on that screen onwards my automation script run.

Comment: i found this 
http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup/
maybe can help you,

there is the same exception that you reported

Comment: Yes similar issue. I'm looking for appium solution if I can skip first screen activity and start second screen activity only. And appium don't exit even my intent is not main first screen activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the APK you can decompile, modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` file (`android:exported="true"` in the Activity you need) and recompile. You can use https://github.com/AndnixSH/APKToolGUI for this purpose.